# How to get value as parameter with multiple same input names?

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

So I have a list in which I loop through and I create the table rows.

```
 @if (Model.TbAuctions != null && Model.TbAuctions.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.TbAuctions)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="~/images/ebayonly.gif" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @{
                                <form asp-page="GetSellerListModel" method="post" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-begin="begin" data-ajax-complete="complete" data-ajax-failure="failed">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="@item.AuctionId" name="auctionId" />
                                    <input id="submitBtn" style="display:none;" type="submit">
                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="myClass" onclick="$('#submitBtn').click();">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AuctionId)</a>
                                </form>
                            }

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
```

Code Behind:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string auctionId)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var itemId = auctionId;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
            throw ex;
        }

        return Page();
    }
```

I have one input hidden field in which I save the value of the AuctionId, so when i click in the a href it clicks the other input via javascript and I send the AuctionId value as a parameter in the Post method. Till now everything is okay, however because the name of the input is always the same, it always takes the first  input value regardless of where you click. What can I do here, so I can get the exact value of the input I clicked ?

P.s. I click the input via <a href because I want 'a' tag styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have serveral inputs which ids are `submitBtn`,you need to make id unique,so that you can click the button which you want.You can do like this:

```
@{ var i = 0;}
@foreach (var item in Model.TbAuctions)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="~/images/ebayonly.gif" />
        </td>
        <td>
            @{
                <form asp-page="GetSellerListModel" method="post" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-begin="begin" data-ajax-complete="complete" data-ajax-failure="failed">
                    <input type="hidden" value="@item.AuctionId" name="auctionId" />
                    <input id="submitBtn@(i)" style="display:none;" type="submit">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="myClass" onclick="$('#submitBtn@(i)').click();">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AuctionId)</a>
                </form>
                i++;
            }

        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will not be able to check it till later, but just to clarify i thought that the problem is the first input i have with the name "auctionId" which is created in the for loop and the result is several inputs will be created with the same name , so the onPost task parameter always gets the first one. Anyway i will check your solution and come back here. Thanks again.

Comment: Just tested it and it worked. Thank you very much.